# Android SlidingDrawer in Eclipse IDE

Tags: android, eclipse, exception, illegalargumentexception, slidingdrawer

I am trying to design an application for Android that makes use of the SlidingDrawer, but I have not been able to use the form (layout?) designer to add this element without producing an exception "IllegalArgumentException: The handle attribute is required and must refer to a valid child."

As of March 17th, I believe I have everything up to date (Eclipse, and the Android SDK).

All the SDK components have been installed.

I have created two Android virtual devices, One for version 1.0, and one for version 2.1 when I figured out that 1.0 didn't support the SlidingDrawer.

I have tried importing the samples provided in the SDK, as well as several other layouts from the web that I have found, all of which produce this same exception.

My programming background is mostly C++, and I consider myself to be a novice programmer, so feel free to talk to me as if I were an idiot so that I will understand.  ^^;

Answer (score 0):

I've come across the same problem.  There is a relevant [Android SDK bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3162)  filed on Google code.  In addition, there is a [discussion on android-developers](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.devel/36722) where an Android developer lists a few things that may cause the issue.  Either way, I still believe that there is a bug, since I tried all the suggestions already.